# Protocol between MTA, MDA, and mailbox in Postfix

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I've read that LMTP is used to manage local messages with no need of queues.
What I don't understand exactly it's how what protocols are involved and then, so please correct me if I'm wrong:

Let's say that one machine has two servers, Postfix and Dovecot, so:

- Does MTA use LMTP to communicate with MDA?
- Does MDA use LMTP to store message into mailbox too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There are plenty of possibilies. Postfix queue manager can

- pipe mail to a command, e.g. 'procmail -a "$EXTENSION"'
- use [Postfix local mail delivery](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) or its own very basic MDA called [virtual](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html), both being able to save emails to virtual mailboxes on local hard drive
- pass the mail via LMTP to an external MDA, e.q. Dovecot

LMTP can use either INET or UNIX sockets. If the Dovecot is installed on the same server, you'd probably prefer UNIX sockets. Both Postfix and Dovecot needs to be [configured accordingly](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP). Main benefits in this kind of setup is that you will be able to use the features Dovecot has, like quota management.

Postfix can also use Dovecot for other purposes like [SASL authentication](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixAndDovecotSASL), so LMTP is not the only protocol they use to communicate with each other.

Comment: And what about how dovecot store messages in mailboxes, does it use some kind of protocol?

Comment: Well, Dovecot stores the messages in mbox (file), Maildir (directory) or dbox, which can be either file or directory based. It writes the files directly with the system calls provided by a POSIX-compliant API. Protocol... I wish there was standardized protocol for locking the mbox files. :)

Comment: Ok, I've got it :) for a moment I was confused reading some docs, there is no need of a network protocol for write and lock files locally :). Now, if I understood well everywhen LMTP exists, it's between only between a MTA and a MDA, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you configure it. On one machine with 2 services, I would expect LMTP is not used at all and if dovecot's LDA is used, postfix is configured to call the dovecot-deliver directly as configured by the mailbox_command option. On a high volume server postfix+dovecot might be configured for LMTP delivery at the cost of additional resources keeping dovecot-lmtp active.

I can't think of any reasons why you would use LMTP intra-LDA, or even if you could. Once the first LDA has accepted the transaction from the MTA, it can't go back and say "Oops, I made a mistake, please requeue this for me or send a bounceback" -- no, LMTP doesn't support queueing or resending and cannot send out-of-band messages back to the MTA. Regardless, I don't think dovecot supports relaying to another LDA via LMTP.

Comment: You got some mistakes here. There are practical reasons for using LMTP even when the servers are on the same machine (and using UNIX sockets instead of TCP/IP). LMTP can't queue messages but it can fail if a user is over quota. Quota management is one of the reasons. AND Dovecot has support for LMTP since 2.x.

Comment: ... Which is what exit codes and extended status codes are for, right?

Comment: Co-operation between Postfix and Dovecot has been changing during the last years. This could be better understood by asking the following questions: Who has the knowledge of available users and mailboxes? Is it a necessity to configure them in two places? What's the best way to communicate this information? LMTP has some solutions for quota management and dynamic address verification (Postfix option "reject_unverified_recipient").

Comment: Ok, I like that reasoning. It allows you to only need to configure the domains on the postfix side without needing to know anything about user management.